# Unit testing to check if a partial view compiles

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, razor

I have the following method which needs to render a view **(This view does not actually exist)**.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetTestPage()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/admin/TestPage.cshtml");
    }
}
```

I have the following test method in a separate class.

```
[TestClass()]
public class HomeControllerTests : Controller
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void GetTestPageTest()
    {
        HomeController hc = new HomeController();
        ActionResult actual = null;
        try
        {
            actual = hc.GetTestPage();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception Caught, Test Fail: " + e.ToString());
            Assert.Fail();
        }
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    }
}
```

**Currently this test passes, but it shouldn't.** I know that I can break the build by setting my `<MvcBuildView>` tag to `true` in the `.csproj` file.

**However, I would like to have a unit test (Using the MS Testing Environment in VS 2012) that will test if the view compiles/exists/sends back a response.**

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "Currently this test passes, but it shouldn't" Why not? Why are you expecting it to fail?

Comment: Because the file for the view doesn't exist. Right now, I think the "types" of the objects are getting compared rather than the actual views. I edited the test method above. **It's more that I would like some way to determine that the view didn't compile, using a unit test**. I am aware that my test method may be far from correct.

Comment: You should be able to render the view with [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

Answer (score 1):

The test does not fail because the `PartialView` method of the controller is just returning an object of type `PartialViewResult` containing the view name that you supplied in the `ViewName` property. When the MVC engine sees this object he says *"Ok, it's a PartialViewResult now I'm supposed to render the view it points to"*, and *then* it crashes if the file does not exist. This of course does not happen in a unit test.

An option for your test could be to phisically check that the file exists (you need of course to do some path manipulation to convert the relative `~/...` view path to a relative or absolute path within your project). I don't know if there's anything else you can do.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing that. I was just hoping there would be some way to get a unique response from the view. But I think you would only be able to do that if you mocked the rendering (which I would like to avoid)

Comment: Another (somewhat hacky) variation is to override the `PartialView` method of the controller (perhaps in a base class) so that when in debug mode the existence of the file is checked, and an exception is thrown if the file is not there.